# How to improve ARIMA outputs?

Tags: time-series, arima, outliers

I have the following data set:

```
foo <- structure(c(38597, 33009, 38668, 39135, 34384, 36942, 46998, 
49620, 40909, 48973, 38565, 53144, 72367, 53217, 38123, 36383, 
43911, 37028, 34652, 28540, 29421, 27469, 28070, 26377, 26604, 
20390, 23239, 28498, 24818, 21424, 21680, 20077, 22005, 21919, 
17172, 27871, 28113, 20190, 24013, 17036, 16742, 18813, 19793, 
19414, 16653, 16273, 14962, 21602, 16547, 17113, 17767, 18868, 
18858, 19276, 17733, 18835, 18934, 19620, 16831, 17525, 17632, 
15146, 21498, 20677, 17468, 19751, 17536, 16998, 14032, 19719, 
16481, 19048, 20401, 18831, 18602, 24852, 36740, 20814, 44061, 
21532, 22502, 18800, 17510, 32047), .Tsp = c(2010, 2016.91666666667, 
12), class = "ts")
```

I have splitted it in 72:12, train:test data sets. 
On train set, manually or using `auto.arima()` I obtain ARIMA(0,1,2) model, however, taking into account the outliers identified by tsoutliers preferred model becomes ARIMA(1,1,1) which gives the following forecasts for comparing with test data:
Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
2016 17323.90 17887.75 17703.34 17763.65 17743.92 17750.37 17748.26 17748.95 17748.72 17748.80 17748.77 17748.78

If you compare it against test data set you will notice that this forecast is unsatisfactory. Give me please some recommendations for its improvement or justifying bad performances?

Comment: What is "unsatisfactory" about your forecast? Related: [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352)

Comment: Fit forecast vs. test data is very poor. The reason lies in leveraging the time series because of including outliers, and additional outliers in test part, am I wright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plot of your time series:

[image: time series]

We note that the beginning of the series obviously behaves very differently from later parts. In addition, there are three large spikes during the last year, i.e., during your test period.

No time series forecasting algorithm will forecast spikes like the last three ones by itself. I would recommend that you investigate what caused these three spikes and include this information in your forecasts. This is *far* more important than finding a "better" ARIMA model.